# Shopify: Unable to retrieve product tags on Thank_You page

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I am developing a Shopify app that need to retrieve current product tags which is ordered/purchased on thank you page. I can retrieve

```
line_items
```

but

```
line_items
```

don't have product tags so is there any solution to retrieve the product tags for the current product that is orders. I want to trigger a console function along with product tags.

Any solution via Ajax call or etc?

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to make a GET request for that product, at which point you can retrieve the tags for it.

`GET /admin/products/#{id}.json?fields=tags`

Via JS on the frontend, you can just query `product-handle.js`

Example:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/products/a-b-c-d-e.js', function(product) {
  console.log('The tags for this product are ' + product.tags);
} );
```

Result:

> The tags for this product are test1,test2

Comment: My app is just for thank_you page (front_end) so from Thank you page can i access to admin? If yes then how?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to do it via JS on the frontend.

Comment: The Ajax API requires that you use a product handle. If you want to use the product ID, you'd likely need to do it elsewhere (in an app for example) and make requests to the REST API using a token.

Here's the Ajax API reference https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api